# Spring web flow : merge 2 war files

Tags: java, spring, web-deployment

Pls support me I can not find any solution for my problem now.
I have 2 projects which use spring-web-flow, they use the same data base, after export them I have 2 war files to deploy. I use server Geronimo 3.0 to deploy them. When I deploy one by one war file, it's run well.

But I have request from my customer is : I need to merge them to become 1 war file. And after deploy, they can working with 2 projects like deploy one by one.
I can not use Maven because my environment is not support to do it.

Best thank for your support.
DT

Comment: I guess you should combine 2 war in one ear

Answer (score 0):

Best thank for your answer, Vipin. I think it's correct solution for my case.
Base on your suggestion, I found this website : https://community.oracle.com/thread/2158079?start=0&tstart=0
And follow it, I can merge 2 war files become 1 ear file.
Cheers, DT